# Ohnesorge Number - why square root?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory, gas

I understood the Weber number, but why would the Ohnesorge Number go like this:
$$Oh = \frac{\text{viscous forces}}{\sqrt{\text{inertia $\cdot$ surface tension}}}$$
Why the root? There seems to be no derivation, as it probably is more of a definition, but then what is the motivation for the root. Does it have anything do to with the geometry of spheres? Or in other words, why do inertia and surface tension count like that?

Comment: You need the square root to make the number dimensionless. Otherwise the Ohnesorge number would depend on your unit system.

Comment: But shouldn't there also be a physical reason? In terms of the variables depending on each other?

Answer (score 1):

Let me take a stab at this (I am not claiming this is correct... but it may guide your thinking).

The "proper" definition of the Ohnesorge number is

$$\rm{Oh} = \frac{\mu}{\sqrt{\rho\sigma L}}$$

If we multiply top and bottom by $v$ - a "characteristic velocity" and by $L^2$ - a "characteristic area" and rearrange a bit, we get

$$\rm{Oh} = \frac{\mu L^2 \frac{v}{L} L}{\sqrt{(\rho v^2 L^3)( \sigma L^2)}}$$

And now things make more sense. The denominator is the geometric mean of kinetic energy (the first bracketed term) and the surface energy (the second bracketed term); the numerator is now also a form of energy - namely the work done by viscosity (viscous force times distance)

I am open to suggestions on how to improve this. As I said - this is speculation, but it looks sensible to me.

Comment: I checked [Ohnesorge's 1936 paper](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1936ZaMM...16..355O), which is less than 2 pages of text, but alas is entirely in German. [This biography](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011PhFl...23l7101M) by McKinley & Renardy suggests thinking about the ratio as that of the viscocapillary time scale, $\eta L/\sigma$, to the Rayleigh timescale for inviscid jet breakup, $\sqrt{\rho L^3/\sigma}$. That said, I like your interpretation too. (I don't deal with viscosity myself, so I don't have much of my own to add.)

Comment: The biography also adds that the Laplace number $\mathrm{Oh}^{-2}$ is the effective Reynolds number when the velocity scale is taken to be the "capillary thinning velocity," $L/t_\mathrm{visc}$, with $t_\mathrm{visc} = \eta L/\sigma$ as before.